# Ubuntu font with Empathy

Tags: fonts, empathy, ubuntu-font-family

Empathy use Ubuntu font for the UI, but the chat texts is in the Sans. How is it possible to use Ubuntu font for them too?

[image: Empathy chat texts in Sans]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s possible through **Dconf Editor** (installed by default since 12.10) or any other tweak application which enables font configuration.

In Dconf Editor:

Go to **org > gnome > desktop > applications > interface**,

Change **document-font-name** to *Ubuntu 11* – 11 is the default size of texts in Unity.

The result:

[image: Empathy chat texts in Ubuntu]

You can also use **gsettings** in Terminal, simply by the command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Ubuntu 11'`

Comment: Gnome tweak has a Font menu where the Document font can be changed (alongside with Window Titles, Monospace, etc). (Empathy seems to ignore the "bold" specification)